# C# While reading data with DataReader cannot update same record

Tags: c#, sqldatareader

i have a problem while reading data with DataReader cannot update same record with same connection. Its getting timeout.

Here is my code listed below:

```
mycon = new DBManager(DataProvider.SqlServer,ConnectionStr);

mycon.Open();

while (mycon.DataReader.Read())
{
    Id = mycon.DataReader["ID"].ToString(); 

    sql.Length = 0; 

    sql.Append("Update [Table1] Set [Name] = XXX Where [ID] = " + Id + "");

    mycon.ExecuteNonQuery(CommandType.Text, sql.ToString());
}
```

and my connection settings are

`Connect Timeout=30;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;pooling=yes`

already fixed that problem using DataTable and looping on it. not cause any problem but i want to use datareader. Anyone can help me about that.

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: Probably your answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538661/datareader-behaviour-with-sql-server-locking

Comment: Why would you want do this? You can just issue a single joined `UPDATE` command to do the whole thing in bulk. Also, you should not be caching `DataReader`, you need to dispose it as soon as you're done. I don't care what `DBManager` does, it's wrong to hold these objects in a cache

Comment: @Steve Yeah its explain to problem thank you.

Comment: @Charlieface my purpose is avoiding any extra usage of memory. its a quartz application which is run every 8 second so time is valued. if there was a 1 row could be sense to dispose. But  `MultipleActiveResultSets=true` gives me a oportunity the do multiple commands execute.
Anyway as Steve's link says query is locking  till end up datareader.

Comment: If time is valued then you should certainly choose an efficient implementation. There is no need to read data and then execute individual updates, you can just do something like `Update t! Set [Name] = 'XXX' FROM [Table1] t1 JOIN OtherQuery q ON q.ID = t1.ID`. What is your outer query, then I can give you a proper answer? And you *always* need to dispose Sql objects. Holding them in a cache is likely to cause memory leaks and hold connections open for too long.

Comment: Outer query gives me multiple row. Rest of the codes does multiple tasks like posting somewhere and arithmetic logic and has to be done 1 by 1. I just want to avoid casting any object(like datatable,list,arry etc..) but seems like its not posible like that way.

Answer (score 0):

> While a **DataReader** is open, the **Connection** is in use exclusively by that **DataReader**. You cannot execute any commands for the **Connection**

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader#:%7E:text=While%20a%20DataReader%20is%20open%2C%20the%20Connection%20is%20in%20use%20exclusively%20by%20that%20DataReader.%20You%20cannot%20execute%20any%20commands%20for%20the%20Connection%2C%20including%20creating%20another%20DataReader%2C%20until%20the%20original%20DataReader%20is%20closed)

You can either use a different connection for the update or collect the ids in a `List` and perform the update after the reader is closed.

Comment: Not quite correct. If the connection string contains the key/value pair [_MultipleActiveResultSets=true_](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/enabling-multiple-active-result-sets) (A.K.A. MARS) the connection (at least an Sql Server Connection) could execute another command, and the OP has shown its connectionstring contains MARS